# mysql curdate method query is not giving correct result

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have two tables one is retailer table and other is visit master table. In retailer table all the shops are stored and in visit master those shops are mentioned in which user has visited. So I want to fetch those retailers shop in which he has not visited for last ten days whether shops are from both tables in visit master those shops in which he has visited and there are some shops in which he has not visited till now which we get from retailer table.

created date column is from retailer table and visit_datetime column is from visit master table.

```
SELECT tbl_retailer.sr_id,
   tbl_retailer.retailer_shop_name,
   tbl_retailer.retailer_id,
   tbl_retailer.tsm_id,
   tbl_retailer.created_date,
   max(tbl_visit_master.visit_DateTime) as last_visit_date,
   max(tbl_feedback.visit_date) as feedback_given_date,
   max(tbl_stock.taken_date) as stock_date,
   max(tbl_promise_order.promise_date) as order_date,
   max(tbl_payment_collection.payment_date) as payment_date
from tbl_retailer
   left join tbl_member on tbl_member.employee_id=tbl_retailer.sr_id
   left join tbl_feedback on tbl_retailer.retailer_id=tbl_feedback.retailer_id
   left join tbl_stock on tbl_retailer.retailer_id=tbl_stock.retailer_id
   left join tbl_promise_order on tbl_retailer.retailer_id=tbl_promise_order.retailer_id
   left join tbl_payment_collection on tbl_retailer.retailer_id=tbl_payment_collection.retailer_id
   left join tbl_visit_master on tbl_retailer.retailer_id=tbl_visit_master.retailer_id 
where tbl_retailer.sr_id=189
group by retailer_id 
having max(tbl_visit_master.visit_DateTime) and tbl_retailer.created_date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY;
```

Comment: It's a question/answer site, not a problem solver ! What is not working in your query ?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: `having max(tbl_visit_master.visit_DateTime) and tbl_retailer.created_date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY;` issue is definitely in this part - it does not correlate to your problem statement

Comment: My result is coming wrong. Is there any problem in a query?